# Loop through lines in .bat and store variables without overwriting

Tags: windows, loops, batch-file

I am trying to store a metric value from a performance counter in a variable

```
FOR /F "tokens=1-2 delims==,¶" %%I IN ('typeperf "\Memory\Available bytes" -sc 1') DO ( 
ECHO I %%I, J %%J
)
```

But each iteration of the for loop overwrites the variables from the preceding line. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

```
@echo off

setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
FOR /F "skip=1 tokens=1-2 delims==,¶" %%I IN ('typeperf "\Memory\Available bytes" -sc 1') DO (
  if "%%~I" equ "Exiting" goto :break
  set "datet=%%~I"
  set "datet=!datet: =!"
  set "!datet!=%%~J"
)
:break
set !datet!
```

Is this what you want to achieve?

Answer (score 1):

```
@ECHO OFF >NUL
SETLOCAL enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion

:: number of samples
set "iiIters=5"
:: iteration counter
set /A "iiCnt=0"

FOR /F "tokens=1-2 delims=," %%I IN (
  'typeperf "\Memory\Available bytes" -sc %iiIters%^| findstr /R ".*\",\".*"') DO (

    set "iiValName[!iiCnt!]=%%~I"
    set "iiValValue[!iiCnt!]=%%~J"
    set /A "iiCnt+=1"
)
:: display result
set ii
```

In above code snippet, data from a performance counter are stored in array-like variables:

- `iiValName[0]` : output format (`CSV` header);
- `iiValValue[0]`: full name of a performance counter (`CSV` header) in the `\\Computer\Object(Instance)\Counter` format;
- `iiValName[n]` : a particular sample date and time (`n >= 1`);
- `iiValValue[n]`: corresponding metric value (`n >= 1`).

**Resources** (required reading):

- (command reference) [An A-Z Index of the Windows CMD command line](http://ss64.com/nt/)
- (additional particularities) [Windows CMD Shell Command Line Syntax](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax.html)
- (`%~I` etc. special page) [Command Line arguments (Parameters)](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-args.html)

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for your answers.  I opted to go with Powershell and achieved the results I wanted with this -

```
`$freespace = Get-Counter "\LogicalDisk(_Total)\% Free Space"
$f = $freespace.countersamples | Select-Object -Property RawValue
$fVal = $f.rawvalue`
```

I just needed a way to store the value of a performance counter in a variable.